# Open edx installation error on Ubuntu 16.4

Tags: python, docker, openedx

I am installing open edx on ubuntu 16.4 using below link tutorial. [installation link](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/installation/index.html)

While hitting below command I am facing issues

**make dev.provision**

```
++ docker-compose exec -T lms bash -c 'source /edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env && cd 

/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform && NO_PYTHON_UNINSTALL=1 paver install_prereqs'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/bin/paver”, line 11, in
sys.exit(main())
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paver/tasks.py”, line 890, in main
_launch_pavement(args)
File “/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paver/tasks.py”, line 858, in _launch_pavement
exec(compile(source, environment.pavement_file, ‘exec’), mod.dict)
File “pavement.py”, line 14, in
from pavelib import *
File “pavelib/init.py”, line 6, in
from . import assets, bok_choy, database, docs, i18n, js_test, prereqs, quality, servers, tests
File “pavelib/assets.py”, line 24, in
from .utils.envs import Env
File “pavelib/utils/envs.py”, line 331
file=sys.stderr,
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Makefile:57: recipe for target ‘dev.provision.run’ failed
make: *** [dev.provision.run] Error 1
```